# Compile SSH into C++ app

Tags: c++, windows, ssh

I need to use SSH to remotely send commands to other servers from a Windows box.  Is there source out there I can use to build SSH into an app so I don't have to use cygwin or anything like that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/) you can use; you could also embed the [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) source code (I believe winscp does this).

Comment: using an ssh.exe that is available with git/winscp ect.